# Как добавить атрибут?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно добавить к списку атрибут `data-simplebar`, чтобы получилось `<ul class'sub-menu' data-simplebar></ul>`

Патаюсь его добавить, но получаю `data-simplebar=""`. Что я сделал не правильно?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
  for (items of subMenu) {
    console.log(items);
    items.toggleAttribute("data-simplebar");
  }
});
```

Comment: Зачем вам это понадобилось? data-* атрибуты созданы как раз для того чтобы хранить определённое значение. Вы можете вместо добавления атрибута data-simplebar, добавлять класс simplebar или какой вы уж там захотите

Comment: каково практическое применение такого атрибута?

Answer (score 0):

1. Либо [setAttribute('data-simplebar', 'value')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Тут второй аргумент - это устанавливаемое значение для атрибута.
2. Либо [toggleAttribute('data-simplebar', true)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute). При использовании этого метода у вас не будет значения у атрибута, а просто появится атрибут с пустым значением.

Comment: Получается data-simplebar="". С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @cracker.s Всмысле? Я же написал, что если использовать `toggle`, то не будет значения у аттрибута. Вам надо `set` использовать, чтобы установить значение, которое хотите

Comment: @cracker.s А что вы ожидаете? Что должно получиться?

Comment: я ожидаю что у меня будет <ul class="sum-menu" data-simplebar></ul>

Comment: Вы так не сможете сделать. Так можно (по-моему) только с аттрибутами у которых значение булево, типа `selected` и `disabled`

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить утрированно, то при `for (items of subMenu)` создаётся некая копия массива оригинала и изменения происходят в этом внутреннем массиве, но не в оригинале. Для решения проблемы можно:

1. Использовать `for in ...`
2. Использовать `subMenu.forEach((item, i)` и внутри писать `subMenu[i]`

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
  subMenu.forEach((item) => {
    item.toggleAttribute("data-simplebar", true);
  });
});
Пробую так, но получаю data-simplebar=""

Comment: там скорее внутри надо `forEach((item, i)` и `subMenu[i]`

Comment: Какая ещё копия? Что-то ты ерунду написал...